# Static vertical sidebar in Github page

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages

I'm trying to set up a Github page and I'm using the [Tactile Theme](https://github.com/jasonlong/tactile-theme) template by Jason Long. I'd like to add a vertical sidebar like the one shown in [this page](http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/current/).*

I'm 100% new to `HTML`, `Javascript`, `CSS` and everything related with page development but I know my way around `python` (a bit) so I'm not *completely* code illiterate.

All I'd need is to be pointed to the snippets of code and files I must add to the template mentioned above to display such a vertical bar and with some luck I can take it from there.

---

*In that page the vertical bar is *not* static, ie: it hides when one scrolls down the page (perhaps I'm using *static* wrong, forgive me if I am and please do correct me) and I'd also like it to always show if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the position:fixed property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pickle, unfortunately I expressed myself poorly. My question is less about having the bar _static_ and more about how to even add such a bar in the first place.

Comment: If you're looking for an answer about how to modify that template specifically, I can't help unfortunately.  Tutorials for this sort of thing are all over though - google for "css sidebar menu" or "css sidebar nav" or "css columns" - that sort of thing.